# How do these phototransistor circuits work?

Tags: phototransistor, darlington, self-induction

In figure 1, when there is insufficient light, the Darlington transistor is biased on, keeping the relay energized. When there is sufficient light, phototransistor FT turns on. I imagine this turning Q1 off and de-energizing the relay but I don't understand why.

In figure 2, why are the collector and emitter shorted?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Which collector and which emitter?  There are three of each, and I don't see any shorts anywhere.

Comment: See the arrow on the "short"? I think that's not a short but a badly drawn diode. Also in circuit 1, with enough light. FT turns on taking all the current from R1, so starving Q1 of base current.

Comment: A diode to protect against reverse CE voltage would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Conceptual circuit

When the current to a charged coil is interrupted, it behaves like a current source - it changes its polarity and tries to pass the same current in the same direction. Because the circuit is broken, the coil increases its voltage tremendously and eventually a breakdown occurs.

So we can represent the relay coil during this state in the CircuitLab conceptual schematic below by a current source.

### No protection

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy5tYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Diode in parallel to the transistor

The "arrow" between the collector and the emitter in the OP's circuit gives the impression of a diode but an ordinary diode there cannot protect the transistor from the back EMF because it is not forward biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f660zp.png)</sup>

### Diode in parallel to the coil

It must be connected in parallel with the inductance (current source hete) to divert the current caused by the back EMF through itself. Thus the collector voltage is limited to Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyA6zW.png)</sup>

### Zener diode in parallel to the transistor

A Zener diode can also protect the transistor from the voltage spike.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgJL0k.png)</sup>

## Real circuit

Finally, let's see it in the real circuit through time by means of the *Time-Domain Simulation*.

### No protection

For this purpose, we drive the transistor base by a 700 mV voltage step (produced by a CSW voltage source)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIGFj8.png)</sup>

... and see the voltage spike during the transition.

[image: STEP 2.1]

### Diode in parallel to the coil

When a (flyback) diode is connected to the coil, the voltage spike is suppressed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzTQ9t.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2.2]

---

The second schematic needs a resistor between the base and emitter of the Darlington transistor.

Answer (score 1):

In Figure 1, R1 feeds a base current to Q1, turning it on.  That in turn feeds a base current to Q2, turning that on, turning on the relay.  If light is then shone on FT, that turns on, diverting the current from R1 to ground, turning off Q1, and hence Q2.

In Figure 2, I would go with the comment by Brian Drummond.  The thing across the terminals of Q2 is probably a diode, to protect it from voltage spikes when the relay is turned off.